# how to share data between sibling component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am dynamically adding list on `button click`.In other words I have a `text field` and `button`
on button click I am adding `input text` in `list`.

my issues is I want to share data between siblings.As I have two sibling component `search` and `ListItems`

I want to send `items` in `list` components to render the list

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-clarke-8dgtd

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Search = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    setState(e.target.value);
  };

  const addItems = () => {
    setItems([...items, state]);
    setState("");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={state} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
      <button onClick={addItems}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};

const Item = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text}
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  );
};

const ListItems = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <ul>{items && items.map((item, key) => <Item key={key} item={item} />)}</ul>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search />
      <ListItems />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Lift the state up and pass it through props https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) up and pass it through props

```js
const Search = ({ addItem }) => {
  const [input, setInpout] = useState("");

  const onChangeHandler = e => {
    setInpout(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    addItem(input);
    setInpout("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={input} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
      <button onClick={handleAddItem}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};

const Item = ({ text }) => (
  <div>
    <span>{text}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </div>
);

const ListItems = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map(text => (
      <Item key={text} text={text} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const addItem = text => setItems(prevState => [...prevState, text]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search addItem={addItem} />
      <ListItems items={items} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bird-7zgch)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the state at the level of the `App` component and then pass down that list to each child component. It would look something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search items={items} setItems={setItems} />
      <ListItems items={items} setItems={setItems} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then you can remove the definitions of `items` from the `Search` component.

As [Asaf Aviv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8605960/asaf-aviv) pointed out, this is commonly called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)